# AWS CloudFormation - resources failed to create error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I was creating a CloudFormation stack using a sample JSON template shown in below link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-opsworks.html

However, I am getting a same error again and again i.e.

[Error link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGA7O.png)

Please help me in troubleshooting the error.

Regards,

Raghav

Comment: can you expand the rows which failed?

Comment: Do you have the aws-opsworks-service-role IAM role present in your account? If you deployed this stack using the default value for Parameter "ServiceRole", which is "aws-opsworks-service-role", then the OpsWork Instance might fail to create due to missing of this IAM role.

Comment: Yes @congbaoguier. There is a default IAM role "aws-opsworks-service-role IAM role" in my account which is created when we first create an OpsWorks stack. The same template was working a day before. I wonder what went wrong now.

Comment: You DB instance failed. Any change on the DB instance? How about DB's IAM role etc?